# Disable Statistics/Analytic Javascript

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, soap, web-hosting

My free webhost appends analytics javascript to all PHP and HTML files. Which is fine, except that I'm using nuSoap to create a WSDL file for a webservice I'm working on.  My darn host adds this to my php-generated WSDL file.

Some people have suggested add this to the .htaccess file:

```
AddType text/xml .php
```

Which is dandy, but it disables the PHP engine as well, and there's no way to generate the WSDL then.

I've searched everywhere, no luck.  Webhost does not respond to emails or support tickets either.

Edit: The script my webhost uses is Histats.  Published by Histats.com.  Also, this JavaScript block falls outside the `<html></html>` tags and won't pass validator.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting your money's worth, then...

Comment: Get a new web host. Of course they don't respond to support requests, they're losing money on you if they do if they're hosting you for free.

Comment: This is host #3, and the best of those three.  The last one dropped my MySQL database, so they have been pretty good to me ;)  When you are a full time student, you kinda have to take what you can get though.

Comment: Try adding a  `<!--` at the end of the page. Other thing that might work is putting `exit();` at the end of the php. Third suggestion is to add the header via php, not htaccess. Put `header('Content-Type: text/xml');` at the beginning of the php.

Comment: you could generate the wsdl file and save the xml to disk rather than generate it dynamically during each request.

Comment: I've tried adding a <!--, but the host puts a comment at the start of their javascript that already ends in -->, which means the javascript still runs.  I will try your other two ideas.  We will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Gerben's comment...

Adding `<!--` does not work.  The host already starts their extra stuff with a comment, and the `-->` that follows gets overridden.

Adding `header('Content-Type: text/xml');` does nothing, the javascript still shows.

HOWEVER!  We've found the answer... putting `exit();` at the end of the PHP script will disable this function!

As a side note to Mr. @Gerben -- Thank you, and I've voted up one of your other answers, so you get credit for this...